# jQuery showing element not working as expected in MVC

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I've added jQuery version 3.4.1 on the main `Layout` view in MVC and I've another view called `Register` with the following simple javascript code:

```
<script src="~/Scripts/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btnRegister').click(function () {
            $('#successModal').modal('show');
        })
    });
</script>
```

But clicking `btnRegister` is not firing in the browser.

This is causing due to the `Layout` view for some reason. To test this condition, when I excluded the `Layout` view from the `Register` view and added jQuery v3.4.1 to the `Register` view, this code started running as expected.

I've made it very sure that no other javaScript library is used by both `Layout` and `Register` views except the given 2 libraries (`jQuery v3.4.1` & `bootstrap.min.js`). For those who want to have a look at the stretched markup in the browser, I've pasted page-source here (https://pastebin.com/U3n3XCbh).

Comment: Please tryig with `$(document).ready()` with because you are using each and element calling separate event. And let me know Your **register page** include **layout** or not and your register page reload or loading content using jquery or ajax response?

Comment: `Register` page is including `Layout`. `Register` page is not loading or reloading content using jQuery or AJAX response at this stage. Can you please demonstrate what you meant by trying with `$(document).ready()`. I'm sorry I couldn't understand it.

Comment: @TanvirArjel are you there?

Comment: It seems you have two elements with `btnRegister` id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to register click event on body click and filter that click base on button id.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('body').on('click', '#btnRegister', function () {
        $('#successModal').modal('show');
    })
});
```

Comment: Thanks. This is working but can you please tell me what was going wrong with my code?

Comment: @mindOverFlow I've added an answer below as to why your code doesn't work and this code does. This answer shows that the click listener is attached to the `body` element and not on the element with `btnRegister` id. But the listener will only be called if the selector matches `#btnRegister` - this is why it works

Comment: As @dunli explain only one element will be bound to a click. it is not good to create multiple elements with same ID.

Comment: above mention, code is a workaround to register click on the body element and further filtering with button id if there are two-element with the same IDs it will be registered for both of them, 
there are many ways to register the same handler to multiple elements like by class or name or custom tags, we used this way when we are creating dynamic elements and need to register an event handler for them or elements has with same ids which is rare case.

Answer (score 1):

Based on the markup you've given, there are two element bearing the `btnRegister` id.

```html
<li id="registerLi">
    <a href="/Account/Login" id="btnRegister">
        <img src="/ximages/key.png" alt="register.png" />
        <span>Login / Register</span>
    </a>
</li>
```

And

```html
<input id="btnRegister" class="btn btn-success" type="button" value="Register" />
```

Only 1 element will be bound to the click event handler you registered, and that is the `a` element.

[Umair Anwaar's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58297916/1953933) is a fix/workaround to your problem, but you should have unique element ids in a page.

Comment: Great explanation dunli. Thank you Sir.